# Simplifying Java method with variable amount of arguments

Tags: java, methods, polygon

Working in java, I was wanting to simplify a draw function (polygon creator) that I am working with. Typically, when you create a polygon, you do this:

```
Polygon mypoly = new Polygon();
mypoly.addPoint(x1, y1);
mypoly.addPoint(x2, y2);
mypoly.addPoint(x3, y3);
Draw.fillPolygon(g, mypoly, Color.blue);
```

I would like to use an image mapper to automatically give me the coordinates, so I could just copy paste them into my own function.

```
myCommand(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
```

Each of these would go into the polygon command on the top. The problem that I am facing though is that when mypoly is created, how would it know how many points to add and where to put them?

I am trying to get `myCommand` to automatically add points as I add arguments, and each point to correspond with the x,y of the original polygon creation method.

Comment: Use [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you need to make use of the [builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern. In pseudocode:

```
PolygonBuilder pb = new PolygonBuilder();
pb.addPoint(1,1);
pb.addPoint(1,2);
// etc...

Polygon p = pb.newPolygon();
```

so the idea is that you provide the builder with a set of points, and it'll generate you the appropriate polygon. Builders are often designed with a [fluent interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). Note that the builder can act like a factory and return you appropriate subclasses of `Polygon` (square, triangle, pentagle etc. if you so wish).

Note that you could instead provide a method that takes a variable number of arguments, using the [Java varargs mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). e.g.

```
public void addPoints(Integer... args) {
   // and iterate here
}
```

You may wish to create a `Point` object to define an x/y coordinate together. Otherwise the above will have to check for an even number of arguments, and those arguments won't be tied together.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) and create the polygon dynamically by using the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#Polygon%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29) that gets arrays of xs and ys

(Code not tested)

```
public Polygon createPolygon(int... points) {
    if (0 != points.length % 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must have even number of points");
    }

    int numOfPoints = points.length / 2;
    int xs = new int[numOfPoints];
    int ys = new int[numOfPoints];
    for (int i=0; i < numOfPoints;i++) {
       xs[i] = points[i*2];
       yx[i] = points[i*2 + 1];
    }

    return new Polygon(xs, ys, numOfPOints);
}
```

Then you can invoke the method with any number of points

`Polygon p = createPolygon(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);`

Comment: +1 All the answers on this page are technically correct but this one gets my upvote because it *only* mentions varargs (the best answer) and doesn't clutter things up with trivia.

Comment: The for loop can be simplified by using `for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2)` instead of `i++`. This way you can get rid of the confusing `i * 2` maths.

Comment: and what would be the index for xs and ys ?

Answer (score 2):

To extend Brian Agnew's answer, it might also be worth adding a Point class which the addPoints method could take in. It could make it slightly easier to add/remove points from your polygon.

```
public final class Point<X,Y>{
    private final X x;
    private final Y y;

    public Point(X x, Y y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public X getX(){return x;}

    public Y getY(){return y;}
}
```

Then you could have a:

```
public void addPoints(Point<Integer,Integer>... points){
    for(Point<Integer,Integer> point:points)
        //your logic
}
```

Comment: [`java.awt.Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) already exists (since 1.0). No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I would typically agree, but for this case using an immutable point class makes some sense, and this code is reusable in many other applications since it uses generics.

Comment: Maybe name the class `ImmutablePoint` to distinguish it and make the code better describe the intent?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use a method that received a varargs (`...`)

You need a wrapper for each point:

```
class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

The method could be:

```
myCommand(Point ... points)
```

For call

```
myCommand(new Point(0,0), new Point(1,1), new Point(0,1));
```

And for draw:

```
Polygon mypoly = new Polygon();
for(Point p : points)
    mypoly.addPoint(p.x,p.y);
Draw.fillPolygon(g,mypoly,Color.blue);
```

Comment: [`java.awt.Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) already exists (since 1.0). No need to re-invent the wheel.